# What is the "horizontal user experience"?

Tags: terminology

I've come across several technical specification documents which refer to the "horizontal user experience" version of some application, but can't find a definition of this term.

It isn't referring to horizontal scrolling, that much is clear. From the context it seems to have something to do with branding.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: I assume it's something about breadth vs depth, but I've never heard the term myself. Do you have any examples of the term's use?

Comment: I can't post text from the documents due to nda limitations. :( Though I did find LinkedIn/Indeed profiles where people claim to have worked on a "horizontal user experience project" at a few manufacturers. It's looking like an industry term for  smartphone & netbook manufacturers. Maybe there is no real definition.

Comment: Horizontal vs vertical prototyping is more common.  Horizontal prototyping when you want to do a broad view of an entire system, and vertical prototyping when you want to study a part of the system in depth.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping#Horizontal_Prototype and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping#Vertical_Prototype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Book]

Definition from [this book](http://books.google.no/books?id=7C2JvUJcQy4C), page 123:

> Vertical usability refers to the usability requirement specific to
>   each platform while horizontal usability is concerned with the
>   cross-platform usability issues of a MUI.

Comment: This make sense to me. Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it refers to the experience a user has regarding the entire brand (and sub-brands) rather than experiencing i. e. the sales process and customer service for one particular product. The latter could be seen as "vertical user experience".

Answer (score 3):

On a consumer level I've always thought it means how the user interacts across all touch-points e.g. web, mobile, tablet, in-store etc. and this includes call-centres, tech support and so on.

From a corporate point of view, for large companies it could be a way of mapping the user experience across the whole value chain. Hmmm, might be interesting to explore that a bit further...